# How can I restore the WSL installation process after a Ctrl+C interrupt?

Tags: windows-10, installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I installed WSL by typing `wsl --install` in cmd, it got stuck on "Installing Ubuntu" for hours. (By the way, it's surprising that there's no progress bar, as the installation package for Ubuntu is quite large. I don't know if this is normal.) So I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>C</kbd> to abort the process.

I then repeated the command to try to restore the installation, but it failed with the following message:

> No action was performed as a system reboot was required

However, after several shutdowns and reboots, the message remains the same. What can I do to continue installing WSL from the point where it stopped?

**Windows version:** Windows 10 version 19044.1348.

Comment: As you have rebooted per the message, try to install a distribution (recommended from the Windows Store). If this fails, add the details to your post, and if System Restore is enabled, perhaps  you could rollback to just before this happened (beware losing a recent app installation or update).

Comment: @harrymc I did what you said and then a "Could't detect hardware" prompt blocked my way. I followed the solutions from <https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-store-cant-detect-my-hardware/b6f223f1-5a73-41db-8c2b-778be1817a2a> but none of them worked. What should I do now?

Comment: @harrymc I did what you said and then a "Could't detect hardware" prompt blocked my way. I followed the solutions from <https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/microsoft-store-cant-detect-my-hardware/b6f223f1-5a73-41db-8c2b-778be1817a2a> but none of them worked. What should I do now?

Comment: If the problem is now with the Microsoft Store, try [this link](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/reset-windows-store-cache). If the Store still doesn't work, try to test Windows integrity by running the commands `chkdsk` and [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your advice. Unluckily, I reset the store, run wsreset.exe as the link says, as well as the two commands you gave, but none of them works.

Comment: So DISM and SFC didn't find anything wrong? The next step is to do a [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, so take the same precautions.